# How to use separate routes for sign_in and sign_up (sessions / registrations) in devise with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

My goal is to only be able to access the sign_up page if you visit a url matching 'invite/:code', i.e. `sign_up: 'invite/:code'` And to keep the sign_in page with default / equivalent functionality.

**I have the sign_up route working great, but sign_in is broken.**

My `routes.rb` file contains the following code:

```
devise_for :users, {
  # skip: [:sessions],
  controllers: {
    omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks",
    registrations: "invite",
  },
  path: '',
  path_names: {
     sign_up: 'invite/:code',
     sign_in: 'sign_in'
  }
}

# as :user do
#   get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
#   post 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#create', as: :user_session
#   delete 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
# end
```

The commented out lines are the ones I am confused about, unsure if I need them.

When I visit `/sign_in` I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"invite"}, missing required keys: [:code]
```

It seems that sign_in is still trying to use my custom registrations controller or something, not sure.

My `rake routes` outputs this bit:

```
new_user_session GET      /sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
user_session POST     /sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#create
```

Here is more `rake routes` stuff:

```
                new_user_session GET      /sign_in(.:format)                            devise/sessions#new
                    user_session POST     /sign_in(.:format)                            devise/sessions#create
            destroy_user_session DELETE   /sign_out(.:format)                           devise/sessions#destroy
user_facebook_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /auth/facebook(.:format)                      users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
 user_facebook_omniauth_callback GET|POST /auth/facebook/callback(.:format)             users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook
               new_user_password GET      /password/new(.:format)                       devise/passwords#new
              edit_user_password GET      /password/edit(.:format)                      devise/passwords#edit
                   user_password PATCH    /password(.:format)                           devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT      /password(.:format)                           devise/passwords#update
                                 POST     /password(.:format)                           devise/passwords#create
        cancel_user_registration GET      /cancel(.:format)                             invite#cancel
           new_user_registration GET      /invite/:code(.:format)                       invite#new
          edit_user_registration GET      /edit(.:format)                               invite#edit
               user_registration PATCH    /                                             invite#update
                                 PUT      /                                             invite#update
                                 DELETE   /                                             invite#destroy
                                 POST     /                                             invite#create
```

Comment: What do your `rake routes` look like?

Comment: @WesFoster just updated the description with that

Answer (score 0):

I was being dumb, didn't look carefully enough at the error message. The error was coming from a partial which was calling the `new_registration_path` helper (sign_up) and I was not passing in `code` as a param.

So the solution was to change this:

```
new_registration_path(resource_name)
```

to this:

```
new_registration_path(resource_name, :code => 'foo')
```